# Multiple TypeScripts Files Configuration

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

Here comes silly and simple question:
I am new to this whole webpack tools.

I have been trying to build a simple web-app using typescript and webpack. In the old days, I created typescript and compile them without bundling them.

With webpack, I already installed necessary loaders, typescript, and jQuery.
The problem is, I have 3 typescript files:

1. main.ts -> imports all assets (images, css) and other typescripts
2. functions.ts -> consist all of my custom functions/modules
3. ui-controller.ts

in functions.ts I always created namespaces such as:

```
module Functions{
    export module StringTools{
       export function IsEmpty(): boolean{
           //some code
       }
    }
}
```

in the browser, I knew that the snippet code above will be called, but it is not recognized in the main.ts (in the run time) even thou I already import it.
This is how I import it in main.ts:

```
import '.src/functions'
```

Any suggestion how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript `module` keyword is confusing, and in version 1.5 it was indeed changed to `namespace` to better reflect it's meaning.  Look [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).

Namespaces are also called internal modules. They are meant to be used when your files are evaluated at the global scope. You can use typescript playground to see how namespaces are transpiled. The point is - namespaces are not modules.

Webpack however, does not evaluate files in the global scope, it evaluates them inside a function in order to provide real module behavior.

So what does make your typescript file into a module? the keywords `export` and `import` (but not inside a namespace like in your example).

Typescript will see those keywords, and will transpile them into commonjs\AMD\es6 `require` or `define` statements, according to your configuration in tsconfig.json. Now you have "real" modules. Then it's Webpack's job to do something (lots of info about that online) with those modules so that they will work in the browser where you don't have modules, but that part is not related to typescript.

TL;DR - 
So how would you do this in Webpack?

```
/* functions.ts */
export function IsEmpty(): boolean{
    //some code
}
```

and

```
/* main.ts */
import {isEmpty} from './functions';
```

if you want better code organisation as suggested by your use of `module StringTools`, just split into different files. You can read more about [es6 import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) syntax for more info.

Comment: So it will require me to change the structure by using import due to webpack?

Comment: no, but I think getting rid of namespaces is the right way to do this.

if you want minimal changes, do `export module Functions`, and from `main.ts` do `import {Functions} from '.src/functions'`

Answer (score 0):

The first part of this answer is that your main `module` (which has been replaced with the `namespace` keyword) is not exported... so there are no exported members for your functions file.

```
export namespace Functions { //...
```

Part two of the answer is that *if you are using modules*, [you don't need to use namespaces as the module is enclosed within its own scope](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/08/stop-mixing-typescript-modules-and-namespaces/).

Working version of the file as you designed it, I'd say drop the wrapping namespace:

functions.ts

```
export namespace StringTools{
   export function IsEmpty(): boolean{
       //some code
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works normally, but with the bundling of webpack, somehow it does not work